How to move values from available section to selected section in dropdown menu
When using the selectByVisibleText() method in Selenium WebDriver, it correctly highlights the desired option in the dropdown, but it doesn’t move the selected value from the “Available Values” section to the “Selected Values” section
This is my DOM HTML structure
<select multiple="multiple" id="lftswitcher1" size="6" class="switch-select custom-select">
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> AAZIZ </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> abieser </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> ABlack1 </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> ACornfie </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> Administrator </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> afabian </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> AFord </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> AGardine </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> AIG Trading Group, Inc. </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> akell91 </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> akeogh </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> akoehle </option>
  <option class="switch-option switch-right" value="[object Object]"> Alan B. Aronowitz </option>

Executed below code:
WebElement visibleElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("lftswitcher1")));
        
Select select2 = new Select(visibleElement);        
select2.selectByVisibleText("AAZIZ");

Refer below UI
eDropdown image
I need to move value from available to selected section dropdown.

A few things... 1. the image in the screenshot does not look like a SELECT element. My guess is that you found a backing element that isn't visible and cannot be interacted with. 2. The text you used is "AAZIZ" when the visible text is showing " AAZIZ " (space on each side). 3. You need to find the ">>" element for the item you want to move and click that. We can't do that for you since you didn't include the URL or relevant HTML for that section of the page.

if it highlights the element in the UI, it does mean your function works well but you need to create another action after the highlight try to click on the green arrow by XPath or whatever or after clicking on the option itself it can open a new tag under it related to the specific arrow
